# psql: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3

Tags: postgresql, endeavouros

after incorrectly reinstalling postgresql on Linux, an error appears:

```
libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file:  No such file or directory
```

I decided to remove postgress and looked at the commands on the Internet. I deleted it first through pacman, but the database still remained, then I got into the system files, found several folders called postgresql and deleted it through the console. A few days later I needed it again and I downloaded it, but after installation I enter pscl and I get this error

OS: endeavourOS (arch linux)